# Format mismatching cells in VBA worksheet comparison macro

Tags: vba, excel

Quick question, below is code snippet of a comparison program that checks two worksheets to find mismatching data. I would like to highlight or format the mismatching cells on the sheet4 but am running into syntax or maybe logic trouble. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub compare2WorkSheets()
Dim varSheetA As Variant, varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long

strRangeToCheck = "A1:AB17000"

Debug.Print Now
varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range(strRangeToCheck)
Debug.Print Now

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
            ' matching cells no format
        Else
            ' mismatch found,format the Sheet4 cells to yellow
            varSheetB(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow '...referencing syntax trouble
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: `varSheetB(iRow, iCol)` is a location in the variant, not on the sheet.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet4").Range(strRangeToCheck).Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow`  You should probably create a varaible for that range though...

Comment: @Tim, worked great thanks, @ Raystafarian thanks for the direction on the mistake I was making.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
Sub CompareRanges()

    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range, arr, r As Long, c As Long

    Set rngA = Range("A1:D4")
    Set rngB = Range("A6:D9")
    'will be evaluated as an array formula
    arr = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=IF(" & rngA.Address & "=" & rngB.Address & ",1,0)")

    For r = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For c = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If Not IsError(arr(r, c)) Then
            rngA(r, c).Interior.Color = IIf(arr(r, c) = 0, vbYellow, vbWhite)
        End If
    Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach that I typically use when trying to find and highlight mismatches. This should have the functionality you're looking for.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare2worksheets()

Dim iCol, iRow As Integer

For iCol = 1 To 27
    For iRow = 1 To 17000
        If Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(iRow, iCol) = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
        'Do Nothing
        Else
        Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next iRow
Next iCol

End Sub
```

Comment: @Tim and Danno, awesome options, thanks for all the inputs!